# C# | WPF | DataGrid - Binding to the sources from two Tables

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, multiple-tables

I have a datagrid, named orderItemsGrid, which contains the columns (or TextColumn Headers, to prevent confusion) Item Name, Unit Price, Quantity, and Amount (Amount=Quantity*unitPrice) of each item that a customer has ordered in an order. I would like to fetch the info to this grid from a SQL Express 2008 R2 Database, called Business, using LINQ to SQL. But the problem is, the columns ItemName and Price exist in the table named ITEMS and the columns Quantity and Amount are in ORDER_ITEMS.

Relationships:
FK_ORDER_ITEMS_ORDERS (OrderID)
FK_ORDER_ITEMS_ITEMS (ItemID)

The database diagram is here:
[image]

Please revert with comments.

Comment: In your query, select only the columns that your datagrid requires, and bind your datagrid to the results of that query.  This will avoid problems with duplicate column names.  

You could also do an AS and name each of your columns, i.e. select price as Price1.  Then bind your datagrid to the appropriate Price column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins in LINQ, that is not problem, in linq query you can create new type with columns what you just need, hat will be properties in that new type, you can give them other names . That list, result of query, can be DataSource for your  grid. If you need help with joins  or query tell